# Hide quantity field for variable product on Woocommerce single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-quantity

I need to hide the quantity field from product page for specific product. I know woocommerce 3.0 has changes a lot of things. Can anyone help

here what I tried with no luck

```
function wc_remove_all_quantity_fields( $return, $product ) {
    switch ( $product->product_type ) :
        case "variable":
            return true;
            break;
        default:    // simple product type
            return false;
        break;
    endswitch;
    }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', 'wc_remove_all_quantity_fields', 10, 2 );
```

I am looking for something like

```
function vpm_remove_quantity_fields( $return, $product ) {
   global $product ;
     if ( $product->is_type('variable') && is_product() ) {
        return true;     
      }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', 'vpm_remove_quantity_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should hide the quantity field for variable products in single product pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'hide_quantity_input_field', 20, 2 );
function hide_quantity_input_field( $args, $product ) {
    if( is_product() && $product->is_type('variable') ){
        $args['min_value'] = $args['max_value'] = 1;
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.